# syntax error at ./perltest.pl line 8, near "$questions{"

Tags: perl

I can't figure out what the syntax error is in this code:

```
my $questions{$question} = $answer
```

I'm trying to assign each question/answer pair to the hash, but I have no idea what the syntax error is.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $text = $cgi->param('splash');
my $anslist = "/home/megaoff/www/limages/anslist.txt";
my $unanslist = "/home/megaoff/www/limages/unansquestions.txt";
open(my $ANS, '<', $anslist) or die "Can't open file: $anslist";
open(my $UNANS, '>>', $unanslist) or die "Can't open file: $unanslist";

while(my $line = <$ANS>) {
    my($question, $answer) = split(/\t/, $line);
    my $questions{$question} = $answer;

}

close($ANS) or die "Couldn't close file: $anslist";
close($UNANS) or die "Couldn't close file: $unanslist";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the hash first, above the `while` loop:

```
my %questions;
```

Then you can assign elements like (note the missing `my`):

```
$questions{$question} = $answer;
```

Comment: +1 in spite of the redundant initializer (`my %questions;` is sufficient, without the empty assignment).

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks.  It makes sense that you can omit the initializer for a value type.

Comment: @Andomar: Perl is dynamically typed so I don't understand your comment. Perhaps it is more that definitions can be omitted for *aggregate* types, which start off empty. But *no* Perl declaration requires an associated definition. Scalars are initialised to `undef` by default.

Comment: @Borodin: Reference types (like a hash ref) are undefined if you do not assign them.  [Value types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type) cannot be undefined, so it makes sense that there is a default value (like an empty hash) when you do not specify one.